# Increase one column value using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a column named `Order` - `Int` in a table. I'm using Entity Framework. I need to Increase a value when I insert a row. i.e.

```
Order 
1 
2 
3 
4
```

When I insert a row with order 2 then all the columns greater than 1 has to increase by one so that

```
Order 
1 
2 (New) 
3 
4 
5
```

And the same has to be reversed when I delete the row with order 2. Also consider on updating case.

Is there an efficient way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about EF, unless to use direct SQL Command execution, but in SQL you can do this way:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)
```

I believe it's better way to use trigger for this purpose, instead of C# code.